# Cannot create file with fopen in new directory

Tags: php

```
$new_file=$data['url']."_files";

if(!is_dir($new_file))
mkdir ($new_file);

echo $new_file=$new_file.'\class.ticket.php';


 $ourFileHandle = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");

echo  fwrite($ourFileHandle, $new_data) or die('cannot write');
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

fwrite() returns 1473

this does not write new file in other directory but creates file '$newfile\class.ticket.php in the same directory.

Can anone explain how i can put file in new directory.

Thanks

Comment: maybe your `$data['url']` is empty..  ?

Comment: Can you try the some code without `mkdir($new_file)`? `fopen()` should create the folder for you if it does not exist.

Comment: Windows user - huh! Maybe you need to escape the \ before the filename, or use the unix-style / instead (which is recognised by PHP on Windows)

Comment: Or use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to make it portable.

Comment: @Mark Baker --Thanks using '/' instead of '\' solved the problem. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

On what operating system is your server running? in linux, directory separator is a forward slash, so maybe that's causing a problem. use the predefined constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to return the correct separator for the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data['url'] = 'foo';
$new_data = '<?php echo \'Hello World!\';';

$new_file=$data['url']."_files";

if(!is_dir($new_file))
  mkdir ($new_file);

$new_file=$new_file.'/class.ticket.php';

$ourFileHandle = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($ourFileHandle, $new_data) or die('cannot write');

fclose($ourFileHandle);
```